# Unable to install packages in Repl.it

Tags: python, replit

I'm using Repl.it in python, and am currently unable to install any new packages. Under the **Packages** tab I find the one I need and try to download it, but it tells me *"(package name) was not installed. There may have been an error- check the Console tab for details"*. In this case I am trying to install `ffmpeg`, but this happens will all other packages as well. Here's what the console tells me:

```
Using version ^1.4 for ffmpeg

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

  AttributeError

  __enter__

  at /opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/utils/helpers.py:98 in download_file
       94│     url, dest, session=None, chunk_size=1024
       95│ ):  # type: (str, str, Optional[requests.Session], int) -> None
       96│     get = requests.get if not session else session.get
       97│ 
    →  98│     with get(url, stream=True) as response:
       99│         response.raise_for_status()
      100│ 
      101│         with open(dest, "wb") as f:
      102│             for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
exit status 1


Replit: Package operation failed.
```

Any idea as to why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: if this happens to all the packages, can you check if you are behind a proxy or some kind of vpn that's blocking the connections?

Comment: Nope, not that I know of

Comment: Maybe it would be something to do with dependencies, but I am not sure. I just tried to install PyAutoGUI on my Replit and it worked actually.